# Compile FFmpeg example code

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-capture, decoding

I was trying to compile an FFmpeg example code [HERE](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering_video.c) that illustrates how to use filters using it's C APIs.

I compiled the code (throuh a universal `make`). As the usage suggests, I'm doing this:

`./filtering_video test.mp4`

But it produces some jumble output on the screen. I was expecting it produces an output `.mp4` file that can be played.

How to run it correctly?

And does it work with **any** given video filter that is passed to FFmpeg through `-vf`, if I simply change the filter description specified?

`const char *filter_descr = "scale=78:24,transpose=cclock";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not produce any output file.

After filtering, `display_frame()` is called, which simply outputs to the console.

```
/* Trivial ASCII grayscale display. */
p0 = frame->data[0];
puts("\033c");
for (y = 0; y < frame->height; y++) {
    p = p0;
    for (x = 0; x < frame->width; x++)
        putchar(" .-+#"[*(p++) / 52]);
    putchar('\n');
    p0 += frame->linesize[0];
}
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: yeah I saw characters. How can I display it visually? e.g. passing to ffplay, storing as a file, etc?

Comment: + does the code work if I simply pass any filter description?

Comment: See the transcoding example

Comment: I changed the description to `freezedetect=n=-60dB:d=8`. But this filter produces metadata, not frames (like `lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_start: 10.01`). How can I show these data instead?